# Extract one line from a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, it seems that i didn't write my question well enough, so let's do this again :

I'm trying to write a function that would take in its parameters one multidimensional array of int and another int :
int ListNum( int tab[][], int n).
 This function goal is to take said array and extract the first line and return a list of its elements without duplicates, as you would have guessed the "int tab[][]" is our array, and the "int n" is the size of a line, i only need to extract the first line of the array so i'm guessing that's all the info i will be needing in my parameters ...

Here's an example of how it's supposed to work : Here's our array ->
Tab[7][2] : 
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
 
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |

And the result would be in a new array and would look like this : | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

Now my problem is that i'm not that good at coding, i've got a rough idea of what i'm supposed to do, but i'm still failing to find a correct solution. Here's what i've done up to now :

```
int listNum(int tab[][], int n){
int i, j, v=0, temp, *x;
x=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
if(x==NULL){
    printf("Error allocation memory !\n");
    return -1;
}
x[0]=tab[0][0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    temp=tab[i][0];
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if (temp==x[j]){
        i++;
        break;
        }
    }
x[v+1]=tab[i][0];
}
return x;
}
```

But yeah, this code is all kinds of wrong, but i have no idea how to fix it, so really ... any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant information, like expected and actual output. Don't put important information like that in a comment.

Comment: Yes, i know, my code is comming, i'm just finding some trouble launching my Linux VM right now and thought i could always ask the question see if anyone can offer any help on the matter before i get my hands on the code. Sorry about that.

@JoachimPileborg Yeah mb, i'm new here and didn't see the edit button so i thought it was kinda like 9gag and you can't edit once posted ( even though now that i think about it, that would be pretty bad ! :x )

Comment: @dx3d , you should read this [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other info on [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @ArunA.S Thanks for the links, i've tried to redo it, i hope i didn't forget anything.

Comment: I suppose you understand that array as function parameter is something you should avoid using because such thing it's automatically 'adjusted' to pointer and this way it creates confusion. It's so recommended to re-write 'int tab[][]' in your 'listNum' parameter list as 'int (*tab)[]' to show better the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get your question though..but herez what i understood " You need to print ONLY(?) the 1st line of the multidimensional array...values shouldnt be repeated..."

you didnt tell if you are reading an MDarray from the user or from a file???

if it was from the user everytime..dont repeat it in the 1st place...store one value only once in the row. and print a[0][i] simple.

if from a file....herez the code..

```
    firstline()
    {  
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) if(a[0][i]!='\O') 
        {
           printf("\t%c",a[0][i];
           for(j=i;j<n;j++) 
            if(a[0][i]==a[0][j]) 
               a[0][j]= '\0' ;
        }
     }
```

if i misunderstood the question...please clarify...

PS: I am not passing Any parameters assuming all are globally decared***

UPDATE

yea got it...try the above code... but in your code :

```
      x [ 0 ] = t a b [ 0 ] [ 0 ] ; 
      f o r ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i + + )
       { t emp = t a b [ i ] [ 0 ] ;    /* Ti0 is the
        column... it should be T[0][i] for 1st row*/
      f o r ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j + + ) 
       { i f ( t emp = = x [ j ] )
       { i + + ; b r e a k ; } } 
     x [ v + 1 ] = t a b [ i ] [ 0 ] ; //tab[0][i]
```

Comment: I tried to keep it short, this was in last year exam in our operating system course, basically the first question was to make a function that would take a 2D array (which is supposed to be a file system with the first line being file numbers and the second data blocks ) and extract just the files numbers so that we can use this function to help us in making another one that would say if the array is fragmented or not. I tried to explain it so that i wouldn't bother everyone with all the details and just get to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

int row[the size of tab's rows] = tab[0];

Answer (score -1):

Catch!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t extract( int a[][7], size_t size, size_t n, int **b )
{
    if ( size <= n )
    {
        *b = NULL;
        return 0;
    }

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( int *p = a[n], *q = a[n]; q != a[n] + 7; ++q )
    {
        int *tmp = a[n];
        while ( tmp != p && *tmp != *q ) ++ tmp;
        if ( tmp == p )
        {
            ++p; ++count;
        }
    }

    *b = malloc( count * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( int *p = *b, *q = a[n]; q != a[n] + 7; ++q )
    {
        int *tmp = *b;
        while ( tmp != p && *tmp != *q ) ++ tmp;
        if ( tmp == p )
        {
            *p++ = *q;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int Tab[2][7] = 
    {
        { 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2 }, 
        { 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3 },
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( Tab ) / sizeof( *Tab );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int *Row;
        size_t n  = extract( Tab, N, i, &Row );

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( "%d ", Row[j] );
        printf( "\n" );

        free( Row );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 3 2 0 
2 1 0 3
```

After statement

*b = malloc( count * sizeof( int ) );

in the function you can insert a check

```
if ( *b != NULL )
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: I down-voted because you used array as function parameter which is the most misleading thing ever. Think about replacing it with just a  pointer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow im sorry to agree with FISOCPP... Simply do it with a Pointer as parameter.